# Monitoring linux free disk space

Tags: linux, disk-space, monitoring

I am looking for a solution that will monitor several linux (maybe windows) hosts on a given network, gathers free space, CPU usage, etc... "counters" and "publishes" this to a central location which is accessible via a web browser in order for me to see which hosts need disk cleanup, etc... Are you aware of any tool like this?

Thanks,
f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitoring Frameworks such as [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/disk-monitoring) provide such functionality.

Comment: This should do it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can choose from a variety of monitoring tools available like

- [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)
- [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/)
- [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)
- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Collecttd](http://collectd.org/)